# Node.js/Express monthly process pulling from API

Tags: node.js, express, setinterval

Is there a proper way to have a timed process that executes on a day of the month, every month, in Node.js?

I need to pull from an external API into my database if any new records appear for that month, but I don't think it would work just to set `setInterval()` since the days of the month vary and such; and I think it would be a bad idea to tie it to requests in any way, but I'd still like to expose a management/admin api to set/monitor/change the updates.

Has anyone implemented something like this in Node?

I guess maybe I'd set a `setInterval()` on a short time and have it pull in/look for changes every cycle? But then that seems inefficient. Can a `setInterval()` be modified from another scope somehow after it's been set?

Comment: Perhaps use [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: @dayuloli I thought about it, but I run multiple platforms and have managed to keep everything platform agnostic so far; I'd really like to keep it in Node if I can.

Comment: There is also `node-cron`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: To avoid any issue in case of crash or reboot while still be platform agnostic, my go-to solution would be to create a file with the timestamp of the time at which the app should pull the data. Then, when your app starts, it reads that file and starts a setTimeout that will wait until the time is reached (or you can start a setInterval that will check the file every minute for example, in case you edit the file manually)

Comment: I would recommend [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda) which I have used extensively to set scheduled tasks. The benefit is that you have the scheduled events stored in a DB for persistence if your node servers restart etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) you can do exactly that, I have used it for these kind of actions

And also [node-cron](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron) as someone said.

Both libraries work very similar

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to end up using node-schedule for its simplicity and since it seems to be receiving more frequent updates, although I'm now trying to figure out how I'll limit persistent access to the returned object to just the the administration routes, but I suppose that rather disconnected from this.